# NHibernate How do i put data in many to many mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

These are my two classes. I did the mapping and the configuration.
Please instruct me how do I put data into this.

```
class Actor
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList <Movies> Movie{ get; set; }
}
class Movies
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList <Actor> Actors{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking here, but I'll try to answer what I think you are asking.

In order to map a many-to-many relationship to the database with Fluent NHibernate for the classes in your question would be as simple as

```
public class ActorMap : ClassMap<Actor>
{
    public ActorMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Movies)
            .Table("Actors_Movies")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ActorId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("MovieId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class MovieMap : ClassMap<Movie>
{
    public MovieMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Actors)
            .Table("Actors_Movies")
            .ParentKeyColumn("ActorId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("MovieId")
            .Inverse();
    }
}
```

The junction table in the database is transparent to the relationship in code; consider this an *artifact* of the impedance mismatch of mapping object oriented code to a relational database.

Now, if you needed to store additional data against the junction table, you would need to expose a type in code to represent the junction table, and add properties to this type for the data you wish to store

```
public class MovieActorAssociation
{
    public MovieActorAssociation(Actor actor, Movie movie)
    {
        Actor = actor;
        Movie = movie;
    }

    protected MovieActorAssociation()
    {
    }

    public virtual Actor Actor { get; protected set; }

    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; protected set; }

    public virtual string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

    public static bool operator ==(MovieActorAssociation left, MovieActorAssociation right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MovieActorAssociation left, MovieActorAssociation right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((MovieActorAssociation)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    protected bool Equals(MovieActorAssociation other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id;
    }
}
```

Now, to map the relationship

```
public class ActorMap : ClassMap<Actor>
{
    public ActorMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.MovieAssociations)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumn("ActorId")
            .Not.KeyNullable();
    }
}

public class MovieActorAssociationMap : ClassMap<MovieActorAssociation>
{
    public MovieActorAssociationMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.SomeOtherProperty);

        References(x => x.Movie)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Column("MovieId")
            .UniqueKey("Movie_Actor");

        References(x => x.Actor)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Column("ActorId")
            .UniqueKey("Movie_Actor");
    }
}

public class MovieMap : ClassMap<Movie>
{
    public MovieMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.ActorAssociations)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumn("MovieId")
            .Not.KeyNullable();
    }
}
```

And to use

```
var actor = new Actor { Name = "Actor Name" };
var movie = new Movie { Name = "Movie Name" };
var association = new MovieActorAssociation(actor, movie);

actor.MovieAssociations.Add(association);
movie.ActorAssociations.Add(association);

// some way of getting a Session
var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{     
    session.Save(actor);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

You may want to consider exposing methods for adding and removing `MovieActorAssociation` types to ensure association *correctness* i.e. that an association added to the property collection on an `Actor` references the `Actor` instance that owns the collection and not another actor instance. You would want similar logic to this for `Movie` types too.